# Spring NullPointerException while injecting Map

Tags: spring

I am trying to inject a Map into a UtilityClass. I have created a Map Bean and I am injecting it using @Resource annotation.

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {

   @Bean
   Map<String, String> testMap(){
      def map = [:]  // Using groovy
      // Putting things into map
      map  
   }
}

@Component
class MyUtilityClass {
   @Resource(name="testMap")
   Map<String, String> testMap
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testMap' defined in com.my.company.config.MyConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
.....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Am I doing something wrong here while injecting the Map. Not sure why the NPE is caused?

UPDATE -
So created a class and added the Map as an attribute of that class. And injected that class as a Bean. It worked correctly and it could inject the Class with the Map in it.

```
 @Configuration
 class MyConfiguration {

     @Bean
     Testclass testClass(){
        def map = [:]  // Using groovy
        // Putting things into map
        new TestClass(testMap: map)
     }
 }



class TestClass {
     Map<String, String> testMap
}
```

So seems like the issue is in the Map being injected.

Comment: I doubt if `@Resource` works well with `@Qualifier`?  In the past it was usually a choice of `@Resource(name="xxx")` vs `@Autowire + @Qualifier`

Comment: I tried @Resource(name="testMap"), But get the same error.

Comment: Is `MyConfiguration` really in effect?

Comment: The problem is in the testMap method. Just put a brakpoint there and run the app in debug mode...

Comment: @Adrian - Yes it is since it has other beans that are injected correctly.

Comment: @Evgeni - the testMap method does not return null. I did pul a breakpoint in the end of the method where it was returning map and I saw it to be populated.

Comment: @Aks make the `@Bean` mothod and `@Configuration` class `public`

Comment: @Evgeni -  I did still no change

Comment: (Have been some time I last used Spring, my questions may be outdated :P )  I wonder if missing setter in your original `MyUtilityClass` is going to cause problem.  I guess the stack trace may give you more hints (e.g. you may be able to guess what it was trying to do when NPE was thrown)